# CDK - How to get stack name in construct

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I wrote a stack in CDK, then I'm generating the template and deploying it through

```
aws cloudformation deploy --template-file "$env:TEMP\template.json" --stack-name myStackName
```

Inside my Stack object, how can I retrieve the "myStackName" passed above to the command? I tried with `.Name` and `.StackName` properties but neither gave me that name.

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

This is done via [pseudo parameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/core-readme.html#pseudo-parameters).

```js
import * as cdk from "@aws-cdk/core";

// in your construct...
const stack = cdk.Stack.of(this);
stack.stackName
```

Answer (score 2):

The recommended approach is this described by alukack. But you can also do

```
Aws.STACK_NAME
```

But as described in the [above link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/core-readme.html#pseudo-parameters)...

> CloudFormation supports a number of pseudo parameters, which resolve
> to useful values at deployment time. CloudFormation pseudo parameters
> can be obtained from static members of the Aws class.
>
> It is generally recommended to access pseudo parameters from the
> scope's stack instead, which guarantees the values produced are
> qualifying the designated stack, which is essential in cases where
> resources are shared cross-stack:

**BTW**: I experienced that the `stack.stackName` returned the id of the stack which I used in CDK.. The correct Stackname used in CFN was only returned from the `Aws.STACK_NAME`.